# Client A can ping server S, but client B cannot

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, asp.net, ping

I moved the question to here from stackoverflow.com

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917569/unable-to-ping-server-from-client-b-but-able-to-ping-from-client-a-please-help

I am trying to configure a IIS 6.0/Windows Server 2003 web server with a ASP.net application.

When I try to ping the server from client computer A I get the following:

```
PING 74.208.192.xxx ==> Ping fails
PING 74.208.192.xxx:80 ==> Ping succeeds!
```

From client computer B, BOTH the pings fail.

```
    PING 74.208.192.xxx ==> Ping fails
    PING 74.208.192.xxx:80 ==> Ping fails with a message 
"Ping request could not find host 74.208.192.xxx:80"
```

Both clients A and B are on the same subnet. The server is outside (a virtual server hosted by an ISP)

I have an ASP.NET application in a virtual directory on the server. In IE or firefox, if I enter `http://74.208.192.xxx/subdir/subdir/../Default.aspx`, it works from both the clients!
The server has default firewall settings but web server enabled (Port 80 is open).

**From client A** (note the different 'reply to' address when the ping succeeds.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>ping 74.208.192.xx

Pinging 74.208.192.xx with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
...
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 74.208.192.xx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>ping 74.208.192.xx:80

Pinging 74.208.192.xx:80 [208.67.216.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 208.67.216.xxx: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=54
...
Reply from 208.67.216.xxx: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 208.67.216.xxx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 32ms, Maximum = 54ms, Average = 38ms
```

**From client B**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user>ping 74.208.192.81

Pinging 74.208.192.81 with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
...
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 74.208.192.81:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Documents and Settings\user>ping 74.208.192.81:80
Ping request could not find host 74.208.192.81:80. Please check the name and try
 again.
```

My main problem is I have a web service (asmx) file and the web service client program is not able to access it from client B, but able to access it from client A. I am trying to find out why and thought this ping issue may shed some light.

I can ping yahoo.com both the computers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question displays a fundamental misunderstanding of basic technology.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ping port numbers, only IP addresses.

If you want to check whether a given port is open on a given host, just use `telnet aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd port`, f.e. `telnet 74.208.192.xxx 80`.

If you try to ping something different that a plain IP address, weird things may happen, because the ping command and/or the underlying TCP/IP stack can try to resolve that string to some *other* address than the one you're trying to contact. As you can see, your ping command gives you this output:

```
Pinging 74.208.192.xx:80 [208.67.216.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:
```

This means it's not actually pinging the IP you asked, but a completely different one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we can ping port numbers.

On client A 74.208.192.xx:80 is resolving to 208.67.216.xxx and that is why ping is successful. Have you checked the hosts file on client A?

Comment: Just checked it...nothing unusual there
Only one entry
127.0.0.1       localhost

Answer (score 0):

Please perform a traceroute to the server to see where your connection is getting lost. Also setup packet monitoring on your router to see if you ping requests are making it out and or back in.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the reason why your ping is successful to 74.208.192.xx:80 is because it's somehow being resolved to some other IP address, and that's the one you're actually pinging.

Since you can connect using a browser from both your clients, I'd guess the problem is not related to connectivity as such, but perhaps something with your web service client, or a firewall on the client computers interfering with it.

I'd check to see if your client (SOAP I assume) has any way of printing out diagnostic information. That might let you find out what's wrong.

You might also try loading the asmx page with your browser(s) and see what pops up, or whether you get any errors. When I load an asmx with the browser, I get an HTML page with a list of methods; see if you can get this far from both your clients.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I did a tracert I got same request timeout. But, I was able to ping the client b from server. While doing a tracert from server to client b. I saw the FQDN(fully qualified domain name) of client b. then, I went back to client and used the same fqdn which was same in my case and replaced the ip part with my destination server ip in that fqdn. I was able to ping the server.

summary: if you are unable to ping a server, you can try pinging the server with FQDN, which resolved the problem in my case.

Best :)